# A strict inequality that follows the condition that $\limsup(x_n\,y_n) \le \limsup(x_n)*\limsup(y_n)\;$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

> A strict inequality that follows the condition that $\limsup(x_n\,y_n) \le \limsup(x_n)*\limsup(y_n)\;$?

I've been trying to figure out what values should I assign the sequences, and I've tried that $$x_n = (-1)^n\,y_n = (-1)^n,$$ but that wouldn't work, since its not $x_n + y_n$.

Any ideas on how to go about this, or examples ?

would be appreciated

Comment: Your attempt just needs a small tuning: take $x_n = \{(-1)^n\}, y_n = \{(-1)^{n + 1}\}$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong but that wouldnt work on my condition it would work on limsup(xn + yn)

Comment: Why? Examine my example more carefully: $x_ny_n \equiv -1$, while $\limsup x_n = \limsup y_n = 1$. Isn't it a strict less than?